# Play Embeded YouTube video using UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube

Embeded Youtube video in UIWebview. How can i play this you tube video using UIWebview when UIButton is pressed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = rect.size;

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

NSString *videoUrl = @"http://http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0";
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"320\" height=\"480\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"></embed></object></div></body></html>",videoUrl,videoUrl]    ;

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];

//[window addSubview:webView];
[webView release]; 

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

When user presses this UIButton it should start playing embedded youtube video

```
UIButton *videoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(VideoAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
UIImage *icn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Video_icon.png"];
[videoButton setImage:icn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *video = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:videoButton];
```

How can i play youtube video.

Thanks for help.

Comment: When the user presses the `videoButton` or the `video barButton`?

Comment: VideoButton which is UIBarButtonItem on UIToolbar

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read the code.

Comment: Why you don't add the `UIWebView *webView` declaration inside the `VideoAction` method?

Comment: By declaring UIWebview inside the video action method how will it play youtube video. I think there has to be some kind of statement indicating to play youtube video.

Comment: Ok, so let's clarify: `Press the button = Play the video in the webView`?? There's no `method` to play a video. When its added to the UIWebView and the webView `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` is equal to NO the video will start playing automatically...

Comment: No i tried it is not working when i press video button nothing happens.

Comment: Your embed code doesn't look right for iOS. http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this :

```
            [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"]]]
            [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: i should try this in video action method or in view did load method.

Comment: put this inside video action method. After you are done withe the video remove it from the view.